# Nvidia GPU driver stops working after Ubuntu (18.04) kernel updates

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I am a Linux beginner and facing the following problem:
My Nvidia GPU driver stopped working from time to time. I now found out that this happens after kernel updates. At the moment my only solution is to deinstall the driver and reinstall it afterwards.
This happens no matter if I use the install script from NVIDIA or install the driver using the ppa repository ppa:graphics-drivers.

Could someone provide me with the appropriate steps to execute so that I do not have to face this trouble anymore and do not have to deinstall and install the driver again?

Comment: This is an effect of using a proprietary binary blob and a GPL wrapper in the kernel to manage it.  You may want to see if there is an appropriate `dkms` package that you can install as well, which would automate the rebuilding of the GPL wrapper on kernel updates.

Comment: Thank you. How do I find an appropriate dkms package?

Comment: Not even that is needed if you install the drivers from the official Ubuntu repository or the graphics drivers PPA. That is the recommended way.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia
How do I find the official graphics driver PPA?

Comment: A clarification: There's the official Ubuntu repositories that contain a few Nvidia drivers already packaged for their Ubuntu release and that don't have the problem you're complaining of now but users may require a newer version that can be obtained by adding the [Graphics Drivers PPA]( https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). But, like any other PPA, it isn't official, PPAs are maintained by individuals, not Canonical. This one, however, is special in the sense that is "semi-official", maintained by a team with close proximity with Canonical.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia
Thank you. I will try this out. This is probably the way I did it with my computer at work. There I am not facing this issue. Unfortunately, I could not remember the way I did it. 
I will try this out and go with the nvidia-410 driver.

Comment: @Sylvia You need to uninstall the drivers you already have before doing so. I think you need to run the some installer with --uninstall argument, but please check for yourself.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia
I just saw in my installation documentation that I had already added the appropriate PPA by executing `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers`.

Comment: @Sylvia OK, after unistalling the what was installed by the Nvidia binary, just open Additional Drivers and select the one you want.

Comment: It happened again. I installed the driver from the PPA, but after the kernel update the driver stopped working.